# Install Docker via a Vagrantfile

Tags: docker, vagrantfile

According to this:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html

> The Vagrant Docker provisioner can automatically install Docker, pull Docker containers, and configure certain containers to run on boot.

however I don't see any instructions on how to do so in this page.

I tried this Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    config.vm.define "vm1"
    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
      d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
    end
end
```

which runs into

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

Stdout from the command:

# Executing docker install script, commit: 36b78b2


Stderr from the command:

+ sh -c echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
+ sh -c apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
```

And this one (from https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.build_image "/vagrant/app"
  end
end
```

runs into:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

I guess the main questions are:

1. why do the official docs (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html ) not work?

and
2. as I'm guessing you need to specify a box why do I get this when I specify a box?

```
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
+ sh -c apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try additionally specifying docker as the provider.

Comment: But I'm wanting Ubuntu as the VM. Hence `config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"` earlier.

Comment: Ok I meant the second example where you are not specifying a VM. For the first example, the error seems self-explanatory: the intrinsic Vagrant method for installing docker is skipping the apt key import. You will need to install Docker inside the VM prior to utilizing the provisioner since the Vagrant install execution is faulty.